# group yearmonth field by quarter in sql server

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a int field in my database which represent year and month like 201501 stands for 2015 Jan,
i need to group by reporting_date field and showcase the quarterly data .The table is in the following format .Reporting_date is an int field rather than a datetime and interest_payment is float

```
reporting_date  interest_payment
200401          5
200402          10
200403          25
200404          15
200406          5
200407          20
200408          25
200410          10
```

the output of the query should like this

```
reporting_date  interest_payment
Q1 -2004          40
Q2 -2004          20
Q3 -2004          40
Q4 -2004          10
```

i tried using the normal group by statement

```
select  reporting_date , sum(interest_payment) as interest_payment from testTable
group by reporting_date
```

but got different result output.Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before grouping you need to calculate report_quarter, which is equal to

```
 (reporting_date%100-1)/3
```

then do select

```
select report_year, 'Q'+cast(report_quarter+1 as varchar(1)), SUM (interest_payment)
from 
(
    select 
        *,
        (reporting_date%100 - 1)/3 as report_quarter,
        reporting_date/100 as report_year
    from @x 
) T
group by report_year, report_quarter
order by report_year, report_quarter
```

Comment: thanks ,but this query groups all the years under q1,q2,q3  qnd q4 buckets ,rather than create 4 buckets for each year .

Comment: i modified my query but since i have shown you the way in the 1st variant you could have done it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems here:

1. You need to convert `reporting_date` into a quarter.
2. You need to `SUM()` the values in `interest_payment` for each quarter. 
   You seem to have the right idea for (2) already, so I'll just help with (1).

If the numbers are all 6 digits (see my comment above) you can just do some numeric manipulation to turn them into quarters.
First, convert into months by dividing by 100 and keeping the remainder: `MOD(reporting_date/100)`.
Then, convert that into a quarter: `MOD(MOD(reporting_date/100)/4)+1`
Add a Q and the year if desired.
Finally, use *that* value in your `GROUP BY`.

You didn't specify which DBMS you are using, so you may have to convert the functions yourself.

Comment: yes the numbers are all 6 digits ,i tried using the MOD but it says it is not a recognized function , iwas using sql server

Comment: For SQL Server you use % as in @ASh's answer